# Get dynamic checkbox values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I can't get the checked values of the dynamic check box. What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/hxfsB/17/

**Markup:**

```
<html>
    <body>
      one<input type="checkbox" name='checkbox0' value="one_name" checked>
     two<input type="checkbox" name='checkbox1' value="one_name1">
     three<input type="checkbox" name='checkbox2' value="one_name2">
         <input type="button" id="envoyer" value="Envoyer Reponse"  /> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#envoyer').click(function(e){
    var myArray=new Array(4);
    for ( var j = 0; j < 3; j++){ 
        var check=$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox'+j+']').is(':checked');
        if(check==true)
            myArray[j]=$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox'+j+']').val();
    }
    alert('check '+" "+myArray[i]);
});
```

Comment: Look at your browser's JavaScript console in the developer tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had an `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`; I've updated your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hxfsB/24/

```
$('#envoyer').click(function(e){
    var myArray = new Array(3);
    for ( var j = 0; j < 3; j++) { 
        var check=$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox'+j+']').is(':checked');
        if(check==true)
            myArray[j]=$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox'+j+']').val();

        // Alert Current Selection //
        alert('check ' + " " + myArray[j] );
    }    
});
```

Keep in mind: `undefined` means the checkbox is NOT selected.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

You have an error when outputting `myArray` in alert (there is no `i` variable defined).

However, your code can be better structured. Here is one solution:

```
$("#envoyer").click(function(e) {
    var myArray = [];
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        myArray.push(this.value);
    });

    alert("Checked: " + myArray.join(","));
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hxfsB/25/

Answer (score 1):

At your title suggests, if you want to get checked check-boxes values, you can do this,

**Javascript:**

```
$('#envoyer').click(function(e){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
        alert(this.value);
    })        
})​
```

**Markup**

```
<html>
    <body>
      one<input type="checkbox" name='checkbox0' value="one_name" checked>
      two<input type="checkbox" name='checkbox1' value="one_name1">
      three<input type="checkbox" name='checkbox2' value="one_name2">
        <input type="button" id="envoyer" value="Envoyer Reponse"  /> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out : http://jsfiddle.net/hxfsB/27/

there is an issue with the selector

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#envoyer').click(function(e){
    var myArray=new Array(3);

    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(i) {
       myArray[i] = $(this).val();
       //alert($(this).val());
    });
}​);​
```

Answer (score 0):

The `i` in `myArray[i]` doesn't exist anywhere. You need to either put the alert inside the for loop and use `myArray[j]` or create a new for loop using `i`